# How to get data with different status on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follow:
all row table is [here](https://github.com/arief-samuel/arief21.azurewebsites.net/blob/main/TempData.md)

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | AccountId | Type | Amount | Status | Created_at | Updated_at |
| 2 | C464E5A9-CEF9-4577-9FC3-183403AAADEB | 1 | 10000.00 | 2 | 2021-09-13 14:03:52.7780671 +07:00 | NULL |
| 3 | 3088452E-B230-4B61-9128-11DD9286FA26 | 1 | 10000.00 | 2 | 2021-09-13 14:05:52.5501061 +07:00 | NULL |
| 4 | B91C6366-191E-48F5-BAA1-3697A8416083 | 1 | 10000.00 | 2 | 2021-09-13 14:05:53.1281797 +07:00 | NULL |
| 5 | 8D97DC8D-EB28-4EE6-A61C-631E897F4BD3 | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:53.6752030 +07:00 | NULL |
| 6 | 7B0F2AE8-51BB-4DF1-9F9E-865D367B1A0F | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:54.1752709 +07:00 | NULL |
| 7 | E30CB16F-0A9B-4FC1-B4A1-0C39F6819823 | 1 | 10000.00 | 2 | 2021-09-13 14:05:54.5555605 +07:00 | NULL |
| 8 | D3E7A826-10C5-4747-8CF5-CA878C2DF9BE | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:54.9322973 +07:00 | NULL |
| 9 | FD9247EF-A000-49C3-9BD9-DF5E57BEC012 | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:55.3237830 +07:00 | NULL |
| 10 | 4181A51D-022D-4E71-97F5-6916C0B7ED49 | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:56.1680657 +07:00 | NULL |
| 11 | 1857DD27-8DE5-44B7-A9EB-A87306E0A061 | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:56.4931063 +07:00 | NULL |

I want to query all unique AccountId where Type is 1 and don't have Status = 1 as opposite the data below.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | AccountId | Type | Amount | Status | Created_at | Updated_at |
| 5 | **8D97DC8D-EB28-4EE6-A61C-631E897F4BD3** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:53.6752030 +07:00 | NULL |
| 6 | **7B0F2AE8-51BB-4DF1-9F9E-865D367B1A0F** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:54.1752709 +07:00 | NULL |
| 8 | **D3E7A826-10C5-4747-8CF5-CA878C2DF9BE** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:54.9322973 +07:00 | NULL |
| 9 | **FD9247EF-A000-49C3-9BD9-DF5E57BEC012** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:55.3237830 +07:00 | NULL |
| 10 | **4181A51D-022D-4E71-97F5-6916C0B7ED49** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:56.1680657 +07:00 | NULL |
| 11 | **1857DD27-8DE5-44B7-A9EB-A87306E0A061** | 1 | 10000.00 | 1 | 2021-09-13 14:05:56.4931063 +07:00 | NULL |

I have try this query :

```
Select AccountId From 
( select AccountId, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY AccountId) AS RowNumber 
  from TempData1 
  where [Status] = 1
  and [Type] =1
) as a 
Where a.RowNumber is null or a.RowNumber <= 0 
group by AccountId
```

but the result is null, anyone can help

**Updated**

here some data while I select all AccountId where the status is 2

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AccountId | Type | Status |
| E30CB16F-0A9B-4FC1-B4A1-0C39F6819823 | 1 | 2 |
| 3088452E-B230-4B61-9128-11DD9286FA26 | 1 | 2 |
| 2BCDB566-D5F6-4966-95B8-12457466F74D | 1 | 2 |
| C464E5A9-CEF9-4577-9FC3-183403AAADEB | 1 | 2 |
| B91C6366-191E-48F5-BAA1-3697A8416083 | 1 | 2 |
| **8D97DC8D-EB28-4EE6-A61C-631E897F4BD3** | 1 | 2 |
| **4181A51D-022D-4E71-97F5-6916C0B7ED49** | 1 | 2 |
| **7B0F2AE8-51BB-4DF1-9F9E-865D367B1A0F** | 1 | 2 |
| **1857DD27-8DE5-44B7-A9EB-A87306E0A061** | 1 | 2 |
| **D3E7A826-10C5-4747-8CF5-CA878C2DF9BE** | 1 | 2 |
| **FD9247EF-A000-49C3-9BD9-DF5E57BEC012** | 1 | 2 |

How to get all AccountId where don't have status = 1
this the expected result:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AccountId | Type | Status |
| E30CB16F-0A9B-4FC1-B4A1-0C39F6819823 | 1 | 2 |
| 3088452E-B230-4B61-9128-11DD9286FA26 | 1 | 2 |
| 2BCDB566-D5F6-4966-95B8-12457466F74D | 1 | 2 |
| C464E5A9-CEF9-4577-9FC3-183403AAADEB | 1 | 2 |
| B91C6366-191E-48F5-BAA1-3697A8416083 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Every account ID appears to be a UUID, and therefore can be expected to always be unique.  Can you post data where a given account actually appears more than once?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is an ID column though separate from the AccountId - AccountId doesn't look like this table's Primary Key

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all accounts where Type is 1 and there is no record exists with the same AccountId and Status = 1.

Checking the existence of a correlated record can be achieved by `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountId 
FROM TempData1 SRC
WHERE [Type] = 1
  AND [Status] <> 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempData1 X WHERE X.[Status] = 1 AND X.AccountId = SRC.AccountId)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to query all unique AccountId where Type is 1 and don't have Status = 1

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select accountid
from tempdata1
where type = 1
group by accountid
having sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If `1` is the minimum status, you can simplify the code to:

```
having min(status) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountId 
FROM TempData1 
WHERE [Status] = 1
  AND [Type] <> 1
```

If you want to count it:

```
SELECT AccountId, COUNT(*)
FROM TempData1 
WHERE [Status] = 1
  AND [Type] <> 1
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Comment: the query doesn't work.

Comment: This is valid SQL - and it does what you described. Exactly what doesn't work? Are you getting a syntax error? Does it not give the data you want?

Comment: yes it is valid TSQL, but it does not give the data I want, it just return empty or null record

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question tbh

Comment: No Problem, but thank for your effort and responses